# Is there any shortcut for // MARK: in Xcode like there is for /// <#Description#>?

Tags: swift, xcode, code-snippets

Is there any keyboard shortcut for '**// MARK:**' in swift like there is for header doc '/// Description' ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is no problem to add it as a code snippet to Xcode.

What you should do is:

- Type: `// MARK:  <#Description#>`, select it and then drag it to the code snippet in the utilities section:

[image]

- Fill the popup form, as follows:

[image]

and that's it!

**Usage:**

As per the screenshot above, the completion handler shortcut is: 'm'; By typing 'm' in the code area, you should see:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. That completion shortcut is absolutely brilliant.

Answer (score 6):

No there isn't any shortcuts for the **//MARK**. However, you can create a code snippet for it and re-use whenever and wherever you want.

Steps:

- Declare a **//MARK** statement on top of extension or method
- Drag the **//MARK** into the code snippet section (it's to the left of object library section at bottom right part of Xcode)
  [image]
- You would be asked to create a name for the snippet. Label it appropriately. And that's it.
- For usage, Drag and drop this snippet anywhere you want

Answer (score 6):

There is one Command we have to use before any function or Methods or top of Coding line.

COMMAND + OPTION + /

If It is top of collectionView methods it will be like

```
// MARK: - CollectionView Methods
```

extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

```
/// Collection Views for Fetured, Popular, Categories
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - collectionView: Data to be provided by service. Collection Views are categoriesCollectionView, popularCollectionView, feturedCollectionView
///   - section: retturn Value from Service
/// - Returns: return Value from Service


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return homeList.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With SwiftUI, creating a code snippet changes by just selecting the MARK line `// MARK:  <#Description#>` and right click the selection, choosing "Create Code Snippet..."

[Selecting and Right Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alBjO.png)

It will open a prompt to create the snippet just like the accepted answer from @Ahmad F

[Prompt to Create Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W40Dp.png)

The usage is the same, just type mark.